# When are “carpet” and “rug” synonymous?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am a speaker of Canadian English. Recently, I saw this video on Youtube about operant conditioning [*link to video*](https://youtu.be/ne6o-uPJarA?t=56) where the speaker says

> "remove something pleasant like the carpet.”

at about 1.03 into the video just as the animation shows someone pulling a rectangle of cloth out from under the dog. But, isn’t that called a rug?

So my question is, why does she say "carpet" in that video? Or is she simply incorrect? I know when I say carpet, I mean the whole floor covering that can’t be moved. But then again, I think about Aladdin and the magic carpet (but really it is a rug!) So, when can we use carpet and rug interchangeably?

Comment: Different people use different words different ways.

Comment: Generally speaking, carpet is understood as wall-to-wall carpeting. And rugs stand alone. However, UK speakers tend to say carpet and not rug. At some level they are synonyms. At others, they are not.

Comment: There are a few things involved, if you read the relevant Wikipedia pages. One is size, and associated with that whether it covers all/most of the floor or just a part, and whether it's fixed or loose. Another is construction: carpets are (usually) woven with a backing and pile. Rugs can be the same, but can be woven without a pile, or made of animal skin, or imitation animal skin. They're not really interchangeable - most people would say something was a carpet or a rug rather than both - but nor are they unambiguously distinguishable.

Comment: The real answer is that they are synonymous when the meaning is clear regardless of which word is used: “I’m so sorry I just spilled wine on your living room rug/carpet.”

Comment: Not all carpets are fitted. It used to be the fashion to have a loose carpet laid over a polished floor such as parquet. However, the thing in the cartoon is clearly a rug, so the illustration doesn't correspond exactly to the voiceover.

Comment: You never hear of a flying rug. Synonyms are never interchangeable in all contexts. I'm sure a 100 ft red carpet would never be referred to as a 'rug' (except in jest), nor a 2 ft by 1 ft covering as  carpet (at least not by many).

Comment: Closure on the grounds of being opinion-based is inappropriate. In this site we have many instances of word contrast that have to be resolved or at least discussed in terms of dictionary definition, context and meaning. Why is this one any different? Leave it open.

Comment: Following up on Anton's comment, while it is true that the boundary between the two concepts is not sharp, that does not make the question a matter of opinion. It can be explained which factors are relevant to distinguishing them and why the boundary is fuzzy, and such an explanation would not be a matter of opinion. The existing answers try to provide such an explanation; the best way to determine whether they do it well is to reopen the question so that they can compete with alternative answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that carpet is a hypernym of rug. That is to say that rugs may be carpets but that not all carpets are rugs. In terms of sets, which I find useful for analysis of meaning, the set of carpets contains the set of rugs. From this perspective, some rugs may be carpets, and the two are then synonymous, although there is no general synonymy.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carpet)
>
> carpet:
>
> thick, woven material for covering floors, or a piece of this material

Some support for the above suggestions may be found in these slightly different definitions of rug:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rug)
>
> Rug:
>
> a piece of thick heavy cloth smaller than a carpet, used for covering the floor or for decoration

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rug)
>
> Rug:
>
> a piece of thick heavy fabric that usually has a nap or pile and is used as a floor covering

> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rug)
>
> Rug:
>
> A floor covering of thick woven material or animal skin, typically not extending over the entire floor.

Comment: A bearskin rug isn't a carpet. Even the definition of rug you quote mentions rugs can be animal skin, while carpet is thick woven material.

Comment: *"the set of carpets contains the set of rugs. From this perspective, some rugs may be carpets"* - *If* the set of carpets contains the set of rugs then *all* rugs are carpets.

Comment: Hollywood: the red carpet. Usually a runner. Never a rug. Any definition must take this into account.

Comment: @Xanne The red carpet is too long to be a rug

Comment: @mplungjan is length a defining characteristic of 'rug'? It's not wall-to-wall. Wall-to-wall is often taken to be a defining characteristic of 'carpet'. The point is not that the rule is wrong, but that the rule may have exceptions (also 'Persian carpet' which are usually not wall-to-wall).

Comment: The red carpet is wall to wall of the path it is on